# Artifacts with semitransparent JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jtextarea

I try to make semitransparent `JTextArea` over image, but when text is written on it, sometimes I get annoying rectangles behind the last letter, this rectangles will appear if I will click on text with mouse.

I'm trying to make transparency in this way:

```
textArea.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 200));
```

Also I tried `setOpaque(false)`, it is not that I want but rectangles does not appear.

Here the example of artifacts:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing only knows how to paint full opaque or fully transparent components, when Swing encounters a component with a semi transparent color, it doesn't know that it needs to paint the components beneath it, you have to cheat.

Start by setting the color to a fully opaque value (`Color.BLACK`).  Create a new class which extends from `JTextArea`, set it's opaque property to `false`, override it's `paintComponent` method, using an `AlphaComposite`, fill the `JTextArea`'s background, using `Graphics#fillRect` and then call `super.paintComponent`, making sure to have reset the `AlphaComposite` first

For example [JTextArea not selectable, but still showing a "ghost" cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329310/jtextarea-not-selectable-but-still-showing-a-ghost-cursor/14329538#14329538)

Comment: I thought about it, but there were hopes that Swing can do it itself. Thank you!